# User Control Refactoring - can I do better than this?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, refactoring

I would like to use the User Control below for three different presentation. Because the objects that are in the passed data context have common interfaces, the only two things that will vary from each presentation will be:

1. the image resource ("imgDepartment")
2. the FilterPanel control (EmployeeFilterPanel)

As it is though, just because of these two items, I need three separate versions of this User with mostly duplicated code.

Can I do that? How?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
    <uc:ListSubjectHeader DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
        Subject="{Binding PresentationSubject}" 
        AddNewItemCommand="{Binding AddCommand}" 
        ImageSource="{StaticResource imgDepartment}" 
                          />
    <local:EmployeeFilterPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding MasterVm}"/>

    <Grid Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
        <common:MasterListingWorkspacesControl />
    </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

[image]

## Update

Solved the image part by setting up a style and adding a PresentationImageUri property to my ViewModel as below:

```
<Style x:Key="ListSubjectHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type uc:ListSubjectHeader}">
    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Subject" Value="{Binding PresentationSubject}" />
    <Setter Property="AddNewItemCommand" Value="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding PresentationImageUri}" />
</Style>
```

Still not sure how to deal with that FilterPanel type yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own stuff but maybe it will help someone else. I wound up using a combination of DataTemplates, a resource converter and a string key in my view model. More details and some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461897/using-a-resource-and-datatemplateselector-from-a-different-assembly)

B

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the **ImageSource** & **DataContext** through codebehind?