# Data bindings in Data Template not working

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datatemplate

I have UserControl to do filtering for several presentations, which in turn has a ContentControl. The content are the individual filtering controls that vary among the presentations.

The scheme works as intended visually, but the data bindings do not. There are no data binding errors in output. The DataContext is from a view model call PimMasterVm, which otherwise seems correctly wired (ie, the status of 5 avalable people, etc)

Can someone help me trouble shoot this?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Filtering Control

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelBorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="myFilterPanel" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="ctrlFilters" 
                            ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=FilterContentKey, Converter={StaticResource filterTemplateContentConv}}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnClearFilter" Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelClearButtonStyle}" />
            <Label x:Name="lblStatus" Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelLabelStyle}" Content="{Binding Status}" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

## Data Template (resource)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="pimFilterContent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <cc:SearchTextBox x:Name="stbLastNameFilter" 
            Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelSearchTextBoxStyle}"
            Text="{Binding Path=LastNameFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        />
        <cc:SearchTextBox x:Name="stbFirstNameFilter" 
            Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelSearchTextBoxStyle}"
            Text="{Binding Path=FirstNameFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is current view model in **DataContext** of the "ctrlFilters" ContentControl, bind it to **Content** property:

```
...

    <ContentControl x:Name="ctrlFilters" 
                    Content="{Binding}"
                    ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=FilterContentKey, Converter={StaticResource filterTemplateContentConv}}" />

...
```